# How to update the content of a label in one usercontrol from another usercontrol?

Tags: wpf

I have 2 usercontrols. OperationPanel and OutPutPanel.These are added into the MainWindow.xaml. How can I update the label in OutPanel when an "Execute" button in OperationPanel clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to solve this, depending on whether you are using MVVM, how proficient you are with OO design (e.g. the "mediator pattern"), and so on.

For a simple solution (off the top of my head), add a static method to your MainWindow.xaml.cs that you call from your "execute" button click. This method would raise an event (again static) that your second user control subscribes to. The code might look something like this:-

```
public static event EventHandler Executed;

public static void RaiseExecutedEvent()
{
    if (Executed != null)
    {
        Executed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

You could also move this code into its own static class for re-usability.

Comment: Thank you it is working when I set the event as static.